Python PyQt ошибка 0xC0000409 почему?
Кто может подсказать, почему выдает ошибку 0xC0000409 при нажатии кнопки? 
Даже не выпадает окно выбора папки.
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.knopka = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.knopka.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 100, 201, 101))
        self.knopka.setObjectName("knopka")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.knopka.clicked.connect(self.getDirectory)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.knopka.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

    def getDirectory(self):  # <-----
        dirlist = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Выбрать папку", ".")
        self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("<br>Выбрали папку: <b>{}</b>".format(dirlist))
        print(dirlist)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.
Всегда запускайте приложение в CMD/консоли/терминале и вы получите реальную ошибку.
'''
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.knopka = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.knopka.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 100, 201, 101))
        self.knopka.setObjectName("knopka")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

#        self.knopka.clicked.connect(self.getDirectory)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.knopka.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 
        self.knopka.clicked.connect(self.getDirectory)

        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self)     # +++
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(330, 100, 400, 300)      # +++
        
    def getDirectory(self):  
# --------------> vvvvvvvvvv <---------------------------------------
        dirlist = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            self, "Выбрать папку", ".")
        self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml(
            "<br>Выбрали папку: <b>{}</b>".format(dirlist))
        print(dirlist)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())



@АртемЧернышов что не так?
